# Dealing with escaped characters in url

Tags: sinatra, rack

I'm trying to map the following url:

> /languages/C%23/most_watched_overall.xml

to this action:

```
get "/languages/:language/:context.xml" do
...
end
```

The problem is that Sinatra doesn't recognize my mapping and I'm not sure where the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about trying it with splats or regex routes? For example:

```
get "/languages/*/:context.xml" do
    params[:splat]
end
```

See:

http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro#Routes

Comment: Thank you, I ended up using a combination of both.